# Could someone explain the diagram about the `lens` library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

If you browse through Lens entry on hackage, Lens Github's repo, or even google about Lens, you will find a lot of partial references such as introductory tutorials/videos, examples, overviews and so on. Since I already know most of the basics, I am looking for a more complete reference that would help me to get more knowledge about the advanced features. In other words, I still have no idea what [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ekmett/lens/images/Hierarchy.png) means and couldn't find a resource complete enough to explain this graphic as a whole. Ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Haddocks are the best in-depth resource. They contain everything, but they might be a bit hard to navigate at first. Just browse around the different modules and make mental notes on what's where, and you'll start to find your way around soon. The diagram you link to is also a very good map of the modules.

However, since you say you don't understand the graphic, I'm going to assume that you don't want an advanced or complete reference. The diagram is actually a very basic, high-level overview of the parts of the `lens` package. If you don't understand the diagram, you should probably wait a bit with the advanced stuff.

When reading this, keep in mind that although the `lens` package started out as a package of, well, lenses, there are now many kinds of *optics* in the package, which obey different laws and are used for different things. "Optic" is the general name for the lens-like things you use to poke at data structures.

Anyway, here's how I read the diagram.

#### The Boxes' Arrangement

For now, just look at the top of the boxes where the name of the optic is written.

1. The top level, the `Fold` and the `Setter`, are the basic optics of `lens`. As you can imagine, a `Setter` is an optic that sets the value of some field. I'm going to elide a bunch of examples here since you say you know most of the basics, but essentially, when you do

   ```
   λ> ellen & age .~ 35
   Person { _name = "Ellen", _age = 35 }
   ```

   then you've used `age` as a `Setter`.
2. A `Getter` is a special kind of `Fold` that allows you to get values out of data structures. (A `Fold` itself only allows you to somehow combine values to a new value, not get them out as they are.) That a `Getter` is a special kind of `Fold` is marked in the graphic by the arrow pointing from `Getter` to `Fold`.
3. If you combine a `Fold` and a `Setter` (i.e. you combine a way to loop over a bunch of values and a way to set single values) you get a `Traversal`. A `Traversal` is an optic that targets multiple elements and lets you set or modify all of them.
4. Further down the chart, if you combine a `Getter` with a `Traversal` you get a `Lens`. This should be familiar to you, as lenses are often talked about as "a combination of a getter and a setter", and you can think of a `Traversal` as a more powerful `Setter`.
5. I'm not going to pretend I know a whole lot about the relations between `Review`, `Prism`, `Iso` and `Equality`. The way I understand it,

   - A `Review` is a basic wrapper around a function `b -> t` where `b` is supposed to be a field inside the `t` structure. So a `Review` takes a single field value and then constructs a whole structure around it. This might seem silly, but it's actually the reverse of a `Getter`, and useful to build prisms.
   - A `Prism` allows you to get and set values within branching types. It's to `Either` what a `Lens` is to tuples. You can't get a value inside an `Either` with just a lens, because it will explode if it hits the `Left` branch.
   - An `Iso` is a very powerful combination of `Lens` and `Prism`, which allows you to freely look "both ways" through optics. While a `Lens` lets you look from a high level onto a pinpoint part of a data structure, an `Iso` lets you also look from that pinpoint part of the data structure up to the high level.
   - An `Equality` is ... I have no idea, sorry.

#### Interlude: Type Signatures

A type signature like `Lens s t a b` might be scary at first, so I'll try to quickly cover what it means. If you look at `Getter`, you'll see its type signature is

```
Getter s a
```

If we think about what a getter conceptually is, this might seem familiar. What is a getter? It's a function from a data structure `s` to a single value `a` which is inside that structure. For example, a function `Person -> Age` is a getter that gets the age from a `Person` object. The corresponding `Getter` simply has the signature

```
Getter Person Age
```

It's really that simple. A `Getter s a` is an optic that can get the `a` from inside the `s`.

The simplified `Lens'` signature should be less scary now. If you had to guess, what is a

```
Lens' Person Age
```

? Easy! It's a `Lens` that can *get and set* (remember how lenses are combinations of getters and setters?) the `Age` field inside a `Person` value. So the same logic you applied to `Getter s a` you can apply to `Lens' s a`.

But what about the `s t a b` part? Well, think about this type:

```
data Person a = { _idField :: a, address :: String }
```

a person is identifiable by some identification value and has an age. Let's say you are identified by a name

```
carolyn :: Person String
carolyn = Person "Carolyn" "North Street 12"
```

What if you have a function `toIdNumber :: String -> Int` which makes an ID number from a string? You might want to do this:

```
λ> carolyn & idField %~ toIdNumber
Person 57123 "North Street 12"
```

but you can't if `idField :: Lens' (Person String) String` because that lens can only deal with `String`s. It doesn't know what it means to turn a string into an integer and stick that into the same spot. That's why we have `Lens s t a b`.

The way I read that signature is "if you give me a function `a -> b`, I will give you a function `s -> t`", where `a` and `b` both refer to the target of the lens, and `s` and `t` refer to the containing data structures. Concrete example: if we had

```
idField :: Lens (Person String) (Person Int) String Int
```

we could do the transformation above. That lens knows how to take a `Person` with a string id field and turn it into a person with an `Int` id field.

So, essentially, a `Lens s t a b` can be read as a "function" `(a -> b) -> (s -> t)`. "Give me a transformation `(a -> b)` to do on my target, and a data structure `s` that contains that target, and I will return to you a data structure `t` where that transformation has been applied."

Of course, it's not actually that function – it's more powerful than that – but you can turn it into that function by giving it to `over` which is part of `Setter`.

#### The Boxes' Contents

The contents of the boxes are simply the most common and/or core operations of each kind of optic. Their types say a lot about what they do, and I'm going to pick a few examples to show what I mean.

Generally, the topmost items are how you construct that kind of optic. For example, the topmost item in the `Getter` box is the `to` function, which constructs a `Getter` from any function `s -> a`. You get a `Traversal` for free from a `Traversable` if you use the `traverse` function.

Then below that are the common operations. You'll for example find `view` under `Getter`, which is how you use a `Getter` to get something out of a data structure. In `Setter`, you find `over` and `set` high up.

(Interesting observation: most boxes seem to contain two dual functions: one way to create the optic, and one way to use them. What's interesting is that those often have almost the same type signature, but flipped compared to each other. Example:

- `to :: (s -> a) -> Getter s a`
- `view :: Getter s a -> (s -> a)`

and

- `unto :: (b -> t) -> Review s t a b`
- `review :: Review s t a b -> (b -> t)`

Just something funny I noticed now.)

#### How I Use the Graphic

I don't normally study the graphic as closely as I have writing this. Mostly, I just peek at `Setter`, `Getter`, `Traversal`, `Lens` and `Prism` and where they are in relation to each other, because those are the optics I use most.

When I know I need to do something, I usually take a quick peek at the graphic to see which boxes contain operations similar to the ones I want to do. (For example, if I have `data Gendered a = Masculine a | Feminine a`, then `_Right` is similar to the hypothetical `_Feminine`.) When I've determined that, I dive into the Haddocks for those modules (in this example, `Prism`), searching for the operations I need.

#### How I Learn About Optics

I learn about optics and how to use them the same way I learn everything. I find a real problem where optics are a good solution, and I try to solve it. I try it and I fail and I try again and I ask for help and I try and I try and I try. Eventually I will succeed. Then I try something slightly different.

By actually using things the way they were meant to be used I collect a lot of useful experience on how they work and such.

#### Bonus: A Personal Misconception

Before I started writing this, I thought you needed `Prism`s to deal with `Maybe` values, because the `Maybe` type is branching, no? Not quite! At least not any more than the `List` type, which you don't need `Prism`s to deal with.

Because the `Maybe` type is a container of zero or one elements, you actually only need a `Traversal` to deal with it. It's when you have two branches which can contain different values that you start needing the full power of the `Prism`. (To *construct* a `Maybe` value you still need the `Review` though.)

I figured this out only when I started to read the diagram very carefully and exploring the modules to figure out the actual, formal differences between the optics. This is the drawback of using my method to learn things. As long as it works, I just wing it. Sometimes that leads to roundabout ways of doing things.

Comment: Just wanted to state I'm still digesting your answer and going through a lot of material, that's why I didn't comment yet, but I'm very grateful for it and it is helping me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @Viclib Taking some time is to be expected. This is stuff it took me months to learn when being at it on and off. :)

Answer (score 1):

The graphic is a flow from what you can do with a weak relationship between two types, to what you can do with a strong relationship.

At the weakest, you can fold over "elements" of type `a` within a type `s`, or you can set the `a` to a `b` within an `s`, changing it to a `t` (where of course, `a` and `b` could be the same, as with `s` and `t`).  At the very bottom, you have equality; one step up, you have isomorphism; then lenses and prisms, etc.

Viewed another way, it flows from most applicable down to least applicable, due to the requirements of the relationship: There are many types that can be folded in terms of some `a` conceptually "within" them; whereas far fewer things will be equal or isomorphic to `a`.